# SQL query to sum the column data based on the same ID's in access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table like below. I want to sum the column data based on same EID's.

```
      EID        value  Description    

      1001        12.9     blah1
      1001        8.9      blah2
      1001        6.7      blah1
      1002        4.0      blah8
      1002        8.0      blah1
      1003        1.0      blah1
      1003        1.9      blah8
      ----
      ----
      Upto 1030
```

And another series starts 2001,2002,2003-----2030.i want to sum of **Value** based on same **EID**

And i want it like

```
       EID        value      

       1001        28.5
       1002        12.0     
       1003        2.9  
       ---         ----
```

how to specify in sql query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select EID, sum(value)
from table
group by EID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select eid, sum(value)
from someTable
group by eid
```